# Can we conclude that $g \in C_c (V)\ $?

Tags: continuity, support-function

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be open and $f \in C_c (U).$ Let $V = U \cap B (0,1)$ be a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ contained in $U.$ Can we conclude that $f \in C_c (V)\ $?

The support of $f$ on $V$ is given by $$\overline {\left \{x \in V\ |\ f(x) \neq 0 \right \}} = \overline {\left \{x \in U\ |\ f(x) \neq 0 \right \} \cap V} \subseteq \text {supp}\ (f) \cap \overline V$$ and, hence the support is compact since the RHS of the inclusion is compact as it's the intersection of a closed set with a compact set and hence the support of $f$ on $V,$ being a closed subset of a compact set, is indeed compact but there is no guarantee that the support is contained in $V.$ So $f$ might not be in $C_c (V),$ according to my logic. But our professor said that it's in $C_c (V).$ I am not getting his point. Could anyone kindly make it clear to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $U = B(0,2)$, and $f:U\to \Bbb R$ continuous compactly supported and satisfying $f(x)=1$ for all $ x \in \overline B(0,3/2)$. (Such a function exists by [Urysohn's lemma](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Urysohn%27s_lemma).) Then $f\equiv 1$ on $B(0,1)=V$, so its restriction to $V$ is not compactly supported.

Comment: But is your $f$ continuous?

Comment: I have a question $:$ Suppose $K \subseteq U$ be compact in the subspace topology. Is it compact on $\mathbb R^n\ $?

Comment: Take an open cover $\{W_{\alpha}\}$ of $K$ in $\mathbb R^n.$ Then $\{W_{\alpha} \cap U \}$ is an open cover of $K$ in the subspace topology on $U.$ Since $K$ is compact in the subspace topology of $U$ the later cover has a finite subcover in $U$ which in turn yields a finite subcover of the former cover in $\mathbb R^n.$ Done!